# How to access multidimensional associative json arrays from AJAX jquery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have to return a return a multidimensional associative arrays from PHP page for a jQuery AJAX function.

This is my PHP page called 'seachsongs.php'

```
     <?php
$brano = $_POST['brano'];

    $sql = "SELECT Titolo, Autore FROM Brani WHERE Titolo = '$brano';";

    $ris = $conn->query($sql);


    while ($row = $ris->fetch_array()) {

        $arr[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode(array('data' => $arr));

    ?>
```

This is my jQuery AJAX function

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $('#nBrano').keyup(function () {

        nomeBrano = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {brano: nomeBrano},
            url: "searchsong.php",
            success: function (data) {
                document.write(data);
                //alert("Prova" + data['data'][0]["Titolo"]);
                /*if (msg != 'null') {
                    $('#similarSongs').css('display', 'block');
                    /*$.each(prova, function (key1, value1) {
                        $.each(value1['two']['three'], function (key1, value1) {
                            document.write('test');
                        });
                    })
                    $('#similarSongs table').html(tabella);
                }
                if (msg == 'null') {
                    $('#similarSongs table').html("Nessun brano simile trovato");
                    $('#similarSongs').css('display', 'block');
                }*/
            },
            error: function () {
                //alert('errore');
            }

        });

    });

});
```

How can I access to array data from jQuery? What is the correct statement?

```
alert(data)
```

print this

```
{"data":[{"0":"Animals","Titolo":"Animals","1":"Martin Garrix","Autore":"Martin Garrix"},{"0":"Animals","Titolo":"Animals","1":"Maron V","Autore":"Maron V"}]}{"data":[{"0":"Animals","Titolo":"Animals","1":"Martin Garrix","Autore":"Martin Garrix"},{"0":"Animals","Titolo":"Animals","1":"Maron V","Autore":"Maron V"}]}
```

PS: sorry form my bad english.

Comment: what will you want to do with `data` after you get it?

Comment: is this from fetchAll in a pdo?

Comment: You could add `dataType: 'json'` to your Ajax call, then jQuery will convert it for you.

Comment: Since AJAX properly interpreted what was returned you can parse the JSON naturally (no need to stringify here @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy). But I would do what at Magnus said about adding a `dataType`. Use `console.log()` rather than `document.write()` and you can place your returned data into HTML elements by using `$('element').html('json bit')`

Comment: @imudin07 I have to use `data` to create a table.
@SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy after `JSON.stringify(your object)` how I can access like a arrays?

Comment: He not passing, he is returning @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy

Comment: @JayBlanchard

I have tried with

`dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(console.log['data']['0']['Titolo']);`

But It isn't works.

Comment: Remove the quotes from the `['0']`

Comment: @JayBlanchard `success: function (data) { alert(console.log['data'][0]['Titolo'])` doesn't work without quotes: alert not appear.

Comment: It appears your JSON is not valid after running it through jsonlint.com PHP returned two copies of the data, which shouldn't be right.

Comment: Have a look at this example using a simple `console.log()` and @Mohammad's loop https://jsfiddle.net/r9vp4ay5/ *after correcting the JSON.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Wait. Now, `alert(data)` print `[object Object]`. Are this an array?

Comment: Yes! You're getting there!

Comment: @JayBlanchard how can I print the first line of this array?

Comment: Do not nest `console.log` inside of `alert`. If you're using `console.log()` (and you should be using it) you have to open the browser's developer tools to see the console. Click `F12`

Comment: Go look at the example I linked above and click 'Run' on the jsfiddle.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have understand the error but I dont know how I can fix it. In `searchsongs.php` this line `while ($row = $ris->fetch_array()) { $arr[] = $row;}` doesn't create a correct json arrays because the arrays the return are the same in the my first post.

Comment: @JayBlanchard console give me a lot of errors 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: json is not defined
    at Object.success (ajax_upload.js:20)
    at i (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
success @ ajax_upload.js:20
i @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2
A @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4
`

Comment: From the example I gave you? Or from your code? If it is your code you need to make the necessary changes for your variable names or I have to change the example to do so.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r9vp4ay5/1/ uses your variable `data` instead of `json`

Comment: This is `ajax.js` http://pastebin.com/dqdFw1du, this is `searchsong.php` http://pastebin.com/kwuwZAZq and this give me a lot of console error that in your link doesn't there.

Comment: @JayBlanchard in this [image](http://i.imgur.com/kdTgQ4X.png) you can see where is the error.

Answer (score 0):

I've set the data type of this request to be `json`, so the response returned should be a `json` object. You can access it by this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nBrano').keyup(function () {
        nomeBrano = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {brano: nomeBrano},
            url: "searchsong.php",
            dataType:'json',
            success: function (response) {
                for(var i=0; i<response['data'].length; i++){
                    console.log(response['data'][i][/*your_target_index*/]);
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                //alert('errore');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[see more about ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: You should include what it is you've changed and why he should use it. Not just post a blob of code...  btw, `document.write(data)` won't be that pretty anymore, since `data` is a json object now.